# How to use multi-level Backbone Router fragments with Apache?

Tags: apache, backbone.js

I'm having troubles getting Apache rewrites to work when directly loading pages with multi-level route fragments. Here are two examples:

Here is my virtual host configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [L]
```

**Example 1:** http://www.fakewebsite.com/products (working)

When I open the Example 1 URL with a single route fragment it loads up without issues using the Apache configuration below. Assets are loaded properly using `http://www.fakewebsite.com/assets/image1.png`.

**Example 2:** http://www.fakewebsite.com/products/12345 (not working)

When I open the Example 2 URL with two fragments the page doesn't load. It doesn't load because all of my css and js files are trying to load from `http://www.fakewebsite.com/products/assets/image1.png`.

How can I get this working for Example 2? I thought using `RewriteBase /` and `RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]` would force all non-html files to use the base rather than the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and standard  way, is to define all your assets with absolute path from the document root:

```
<img src="/assets/image1.png">
```

Comment: That certainly is one solution. The reason I didn't do this is because I switch between a localhost subdirectory for testing and production.